# Symfony authenticator supports() function is called twice

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I got this project in PHP/Symfony 6.3; authentication is done via a header token like 'X-Api-Token' - so my authenticator has a function `supports()` like this :

```php
public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
{
    if (null !== $request->headers->get('X-Api-Token')) {
        // try to decode the token and returns true if the token is OK
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `authenticate()` function then makes the appropriate SQL query to validate the token (I know this is not perfect, but I'll take care of this later).

When adding debug, like a dump() function at the beginning of the function, i see that this support function is called twice by the kernel.onRequest event.

I searched everywhere and still can't get why is it so. What could be the reason for this function to be called twice in a single request ?

Comment: Is one of the requests possibly a sub-request?

Comment: @ChrisHaas : not sure but I don't think so : this is only for API calls with JsonResponses.

Comment: The `Request` class has several things to inspect, including if it is a main or sub request. You might also want to check the method, it is possible that one of the calls is a HEAD request.